# Как с двух записей в табличке сделать одну?

Tags: php

У нас есть табличка, назовем ее inv, у нее есть 3 столбика: `kolovo`, `id_item`, `username`. Вытягиваем все записи с идентификатором username, и тут такая штука, попалось два одинаковых итема. Пускай, они имеют `id_item` = 1 , Вопрос, как с этих двух записей сделать одну, но учитывать, что их количество разное, у одного итема количество = 10, а у другого = 20, нам нужно с этих двух записей сделать одну, и чтоб это запись имела количество 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(kolovo) as k, count(*) as cnt, id_item , username FROM inv group by id_item, username having cnt > 1;
```

потом перебираем всё что нам вернул запрос.

```
while($row = fetch()) {
    delete from inv where item_id='.$row['id_item'].' and username='.$row['username'];
    insert into inv (id_item, username, kolovo) values ('.$row['id_item'].', '.$row['username'].', '.$row['k'].');
}
```

Тут понятное дело псевдокод, нужно ескейпить и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Делай вот такой SQL запрос:

```
Select sum(kolovo), id_item , username FROM inv WEARE username = "id вашего пользователя" group by (id_item, username);
```

Comment: Должно заработать.